# JSP NullPointer StandardWrapperValve[servlets. ]: Servlet.service() for servlet servlets. threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to learn how to work with JSP. And I encountered something, which makes no sense, at least in my opinion:

When I try to run:

```
response.getWriter().println(m.getDb().printAll());
```

I get this when trying to load the page in question:

```
2014-08-16T03:19:59.789+0200|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[servlets.GUI]: Servlet.service() for servlet servlets.GUI threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
at servlets.GUI.doGet(GUI.java:39)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
```

at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

But when I run:

```
response.getWriter().println(m.getOut());
```

The output is correct.

Both should return the same result since

```
class M
{
 String out = "";

 private OjectDAO db = new ObjectDAO()

 public M()
 {
   db.addAll(TextFileLoader(getServletContext().getRealPath("textfile.xml"))); 
 }


 ...
        System.out.println(db.printAll());
        out=db.printAll();
 ...
     public String getOut()
     {
      return out;
     }
 ...
}
```

and

```
class ObjectDAO
{

 ...
 public String printAll()
 {
  String result = "";
  for (WrappedItem item : locDB )
  {
   result = item.toString() + result + "\n";
  }
  return result;
 }
  ...
}
```

Why is it, that in one case there is a NullPointer and in the other case there is none?

More detail:
Application runs on Glassfish 4 deployed by Eclipse Luna. OS : Debian
The application loads text from a file to a DAO and tries to load them from the DAO into the JSP. Path to the xml seems correct.

P.S.: At first I thought that it was a BuildPath problem, because I encountered something similar before and that was solved once I added JDom2.jar to WEB-INF/lib , but frankly I don't see where I could add a jar this time. Funny thing is: Even while having both problems, the output to STDOUT was working seamlessly.

#### Addendum 1

As I stated above, my problem is:

```
response.getWriter().println(m.getOut());
```

works fine.

```
response.getWriter().println(m.getDb().printAll());
```

doesn't.

Both lines are placed in the servlet "GUI.java" file.
The only difference, at least in how muc I see is:
In the first case I print the String after it passes through a String variable in class M, in the second case I try to print it directly.

That is all the difference.

#### Addendum 2

Added the full stack trace.

Servlet: Generic code, the only difference is

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    System.out.println("Started ");
    response.getWriter().println("<h1> Header1 </h1>");
    response.getWriter().println("<body> Funny body text </body>");
    System.out.println(getServletContext().getRealPath("data.xml"));
    serverJava.Monitor m = new serverJava.Monitor(getServletContext().getRealPath("data.xml"));
    response.getWriter().println("<br> I say:" + m.printHello());
    response.getWriter().println(m.getOut());
    response.getWriter().println(m.getDb().printAll());
}
```

Now before people start: The following code was just to test, whether everything works ok. It's not really there to stay.

```
public M(String s) 
{
    try
    {
        XMLFileWrapper xml = new XMLFileWrapper(s);
        DataDAO db = new DataDAO();
        db.loadFromHDD(xml.retrieveWrappedRootDataFromXML());
        System.out.println(db.printAll()); <<<< This yealds output
        out=db.printAll(); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public DataDAO getDb() 
{
    return db;
}

public String getOut()
{
    return out;
}
```

.

```
public class DataDAO 
{

    public void loadFromHDD(LinkedList<Item> list)
    {
        locDB.addAll(list);
    }

    public String printAll()
    {
        String result = "";
        for (Item item : locDB )
        {
        result = item.toString() + result + "\n";
        }
    return result;
    }

}
```

DataDAO retrieves content from a JDom2 object... and while I doubt it has got anything to do with it, here is the method:

```
public LinkedList<Item> retrieveWrappedRootDataFromXML()
{
    LinkedList<Item> result = new LinkedList<Item>();

    for ( Element e : getRoot().getChildren() )
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setInfoId(e.getAttributeValue("id"));
        item.setName(e.getChildText("name"));
        item.setShortName(e.getChildText("short"));
        item.setUser(e.getChildText("user"));
        result.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: *"Funny thing is: Even while having both problems, the output to STDOUT was working seamlessly."* - Are you sure you are deploying properly, and that the deployment is actually working?  That "funny thing" is hinting that you are not actually running the code that you think you are running.

Comment: I did go through the project and found nothing that would indicate to me that I'm running wrong code... but as usual, I may be wrong. Any hints on what I may have overlooked?

Comment: I would put each instruction on its own line, and try again/use a debugger with a `NullPointerException` breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets approach this logically.

The following statement can (in theory) throw `NullPointerException` for the following reasons:

```
  response.getWriter().println(m.getDb().printAll());
```

1. `response` is `null`.
2. `response.getWriter()` returns `null`
3. `m` is `null`
4. `m.getDb()` is `null`

The 1 and 2 we can eliminate from what the JSP spec says.  (Unless you did something truly bizarre ...)

The 3 we can (tentatively) eliminate on the basis that this statement:

```
  response.getWriter().println(m.getOut());
```

works in (I assume) a similar context.  That implies `m` isn't `null`.  (Though given the other inaccuracies in the evidence in your Question, we can't be definite about that ...)

That leaves 4 as the most likely cause.  Check that you have implemented `getDb()` correctly; e.g. make sure that the `ObjectDAO` value it returns can't be `null`.

---

Note we can't be certain about *any* of this, because the code snippets in your Question are clearly "fictional".  They contain obvious typos that the compiler would reject.  Hence, we can't trust that they actually bear much resemblance to the *actual* code in your JSP.

---

**UPDATE**

Now that you have posted the full code of the `M` class, the cause of the NPE just leaps off the page at me!

The `getDb()` method returns `null` because `db` is not initialized.

*"But"* I hear you say *"it is!!"*.

Oh no it isn't!  You are assigning `new DataDAO()` to a local variable `db`, not to `this.db`.

---

Lesson: when indisputable logic tells you that the cause of a bug must be X, it doesn't pay to argue ...

Comment: Well... Actually... that is the thing. Neither is happening.

The snippets are "fictional" because I just require an explanation of this this one strange occurrence.

M isn't null. Output in console presents the data every single time. 

I tried to check this about 16 hours back by simply copying the project sources into a different project and it worked seamlessly.

That's how I got so surprised [ and that's how I with additional help from Google found about the missing library ] ... because after adding the library the above / more or less / is what I arrived to.

See addendum 1 in OP.

Comment: There is no other logical explanation if I take your evidence at face value.  If you want me to look into this further, you will need to provide an SSCCE; i.e. a small JSP + Java class that behaves as you describe that other people can run ... to see what is going on.

Comment: It would also help if you provided the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Added everything I could think of... Addendum 2

Comment: By the way, that isn't an SSCCE.  The code still isn't *self contained*.  We still have to add stuff to make it executable. But no matter, I can see what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you... Once pointed out I feel like hitting my head against the wall repeatedly.  
Lesson 2: When your brain tells you, that you need to sleep, ignore your body being all vibrant and eager for work, get a bottle of scotch, vodka, sleeping pills or whatever works for you and go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I mistakenly typed, eg. `productDAO proddao;`, it should be `productDAO proddao= new productDAO();` and the program works